# table with first row - 1 cell, second row - 2 cells, 3rd row - 3 cells

Tags: html, css

How can I make such a table, with first row - 1 cell, second row - 2 cells, 3rd row - 3 cells with all cells in each row having **same size**?
Is it possible?

Comment: Try something. There are plenty of free HTML editor apps on the web that will do this for you.

Comment: Why particularly do you want this as a table - is this for content or layout purposes? If its for layout purposes then I would suggest not using a table, and rather use div's with a grid system. Think Boootsrap or 960-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one more simple solution

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;

}
.td_b {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="td_b">1st</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="td_b">1st</td>
      <td class="td_b">2nd</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="td_b">1st</td>
      <td class="td_b">2nd</td>
      <td class="td_b">3rd</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2suuasp/) link to that

Yet another solution is:

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.td_1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.td_2 {
  width: 50%;
}
.td_3 {
  width: 33%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td_1" colspan="6">1st</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td_2" colspan="3">1st</td>
    <td class="td_2" colspan="3">2nd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td_3" colspan="2">1st</td>
    <td class="td_3" colspan="2">2nd</td>
    <td class="td_3" colspan="2">3rd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLp3w2g2/) example

Answer (score 1):

One oldskool trick is to nest a table in the third row. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.two-column {
 width: 50%;
}
.three-column {
  width: 33.3%;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Row 1 column 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="two-column">Row 2 column 1</td>
    <td class="two-column" colspan="2">Row 2 column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <table class="my-nested-table">
            <tr>
                <td class="three-column">Row 3 column 1</td>
                <td class="three-column">Row 3 column 2</td>
                <td class="three-column">Row 3 column 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, so why did I get thumbs down? It seems that it is a good challenge, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure why you got a thumbs down. Was not me who down-voted it. If you are happy with my answer then please feel free to vote it as correct :-)

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working :-(

Comment: I tested it and it does work. Copy my code as it into its own table.html file and test on your Desktop. Add table, td { border: 1px solid red; } so you can see where the cells end.

Comment: Ok, it may be a cross-broser thing. Works in Safari but not Chrome. Change colspan="2" to colspan="3" everywhere in the code above. I will see if I can edit